# How to remove excess whitespace from a string by jQuery and only count the actual number of characters?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

today I want to design a block text more than 70 characters will hide the extra text and appear show more
But I can't predict if the user will add extra blank lines, which will cause them to be counted as a character. How do I remove the extra white space and count only the parts that actually have words?

```js
$(function(){
    let len = 70
    $('.demo').each(function(){ 
        if($(this).html().length >len){   
            var str=$(this).html().substring(0,len-1)+"<a class='more'>...顯示更多</a>";
            $(this).html(str);
        } 
    });
});
```

```css
.content{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  border:1px solid #222;
  padding:10px;
}

.demo{
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:clip;
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient:vertical;  
  -webkit-line-clamp:2;
}

.photo{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px;
  border-radius:16px; 
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.more{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="demo">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur Lore
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
  </div>
  <img  class="photo" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622734659223-f995527e6c7b?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: use `trim()` function on string like `string.trim()`

Comment: It's unclear if your issue is *only* with lines at the end (or start).  If you want to remove whitespace from the middle as well, you'll need a regex, eg `str = str.replace(/\W{2,}/g, " ")` will convert all occurrences of multiple white spaces to a single space [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kJeL89/1/).   You may prefer just spaces or just newlines rather than any combination of whitespaces.

Comment: @freedomn-m  hello~
You said you need to add your regular expression if you want to remove whitespace from text, but I haven't learned it yet!

Where does STR = STR. Replace (/\W{2,}/g, "") place it in my program?

[link](https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/YzZLZVp?editors=1010)



Thank you

Comment: `if($(this).html().replace(/\W{2,}/g, " ").trim().length >len){` then again when you get the .html() to truncate.   Or put it in a variable before the `if` and don't do the same thing twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.trim()` as in `if ($(this).html().trim().length > len) {`

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  let len = 70
  $('.demo').each(function() {
    if ($(this).html().trim().length > len) {
      var str = $(this).html().substring(0, len - 1) + "<a class='more'>...顯示更多</a>";
      $(this).html(str);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  padding: 10px;
}

.demo {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
}

.photo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.more {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="demo">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur Lore












  </div>
  <img class="photo" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622734659223-f995527e6c7b?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you ~ for telling me the method and showing me a demo to make it easier for me to understand how to correct it so that I can learn new methods!

In addition, I would like to ask if the user has a lot of blank space but the text actually has a lot of how to make the text fill two lines, so that the redundant text can be hidden and displayed more?